# Garbage Collection for BinaryReader/FilesStream

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, filestream, binaryreader

I am currently baffled by C# garbage collection of the following code. It is almost as if it doesn't believe the object should be thrown away.

```
using (br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("mydata.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)))
{ 
    byte[] blah = br.ReadBytes(364000000);
}
```

I have tried `System.GC.Collect();` `br.Close();` `br.Dispose();` all to no avail. Unfortunately, because I need to open multiple large files, I get an out of memory exception. Obviously I can read the bytes incrementally instead of all at once, but I am trying to understand/resolve the underlying issue of it holding onto the memory.

Comment: It's hard to tell what could be wrong from the code you posted (which should be OK).

Comment: Are you saying that exact code produces an OOM exception? if not what do you do with `blah[]` in reality? - The `using` should ensure the reader & stream are disposed appropriately.

Comment: Does the encapsulation work, so both the reader as well as the stream are disposed? Or shouldn't you use two nested usings, with the outer one for the FileStream?

Comment: Have you tried to run a memory profiler to find out which objects survive?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with garbage collection.  Creating such a huge array fails because the operating system cannot find a big enough hole in the available address space.  It will work right after you start the program but those odds go down quickly as the address space gets fragmented.  Otherwise a very old-fashioned problem that has a trivial solution: Project > Properties > Build tab > untick the "Prefer 32-bit" option.  You don't prefer it, 64-bit code has a ~4 terabyte address space, you can't run out of big holes.

Comment: That initial read doesn't create an exception, it is if I do that function another 4 times or so in a row. However, I have just experimented and if I split the ReadBytes by a factor of 10, garbage collection seems to kick in before I get the exception in subsequent iterations. It may be down to garbage collection being based on the number of pointers as opposed to amount or memory? May be down to the size of array as you say.

Comment: @LanderMan if you do `GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true);` and the problem goes away using the big size it is as Hans said, it is caused by memory fragmentation not being able to find a spot large enough to allocate the array.